# Bad Performance OpenCL based OpenCV Squares Implemenation

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

Trying to run the generic squares.cpp example:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/ocl/squares.cpp

I have a Macbook Pro with an AMD Radeon HD 6750M with the correct OpenCL libraries installed to /opt/AMDAPP as well as a CMake compiled OpenCV2.4 that detected the CL libraries properly. Furthermore I am using fglrx-updates to take advantage of the proprietary drivers. However, it seems like the performance is almost 2x as bad as the CPP runtime. I tried it for ~200 iterations and had the same issue.

Built with: g++ -o square.out square.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/AMDAPP/lib -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/AMDAPP/include -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_imgproc -lOpenCL

Results:

cpp average time: 233.192ms

ocl average time: 568.043ms

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: I think the question was implied: why the hardware accelerated version is slower than the CPU one.

Comment: Yup. Why would the GPU scenario be slower?

Comment: The first time you run an OpenCL kernel, the GPU still has to come out of power saving mode, so this run always takes longer.  Normally, one would loop over the operation a few times to wake up the GPU, then time a second loop that repeats the operation a few hundred times.

Comment: Understandable. Thus I mentioned running it for ~200 iterations

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same behaviour on Windows with a FirePro V5900

```
cpp: 66ms
ocl: 90ms
```

The sample does a warm-up step. Perhaps not enough iterations.